# HAVING ANY and HAVING EVERY

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, having

Does SQL Server 2005 support `ANY` or `EVERY` with `HAVING`?

Suppose I have two tables:

```
Training(TrainingID, TrainingCloseDate) and
TrainingDetail(TrainingDetailID, TrainingID, LKClassCode, CompletionDate).
```

For one `TrainingID`, there can be multiple values in `TrainingDetail` with different `LKClassCode`. I need to find all the `TrainingID`'s which have at least one `TrainingDetailID` with `CompletionDate` between 1/1/2009 and 1/1/2010.

When I tried with `HAVING ANY`, I got an error:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ANY'.
```

If it is not supported, could you please suggest an alternative?

What if I need to find all the `TrainingID`'s which have 'at least one `TrainingDetailID` with `CompletionDate` between 1/1/2009 and 1/1/2010 or the `TrainingCloseDate` = '5/5/2009' '?

Answer (score 0):

*I need to find all the `TrainingID`'s which have at least one `TrainingDetailID` with `CompletionDate` between 1/1/2009 and 1/1/2010.*

```
SELECT TrainingID
FROM TrainingDetail
WHERE CompletionDate BETWEEN date1 AND date2
```

You might need to convert dates to proper format (timestamp?).

*What if I need to find all the `TrainingID`'s which have 'at least one `TrainingDetailID` with `CompletionDate` between 1/1/2009 and 1/1/2010 or the `TrainingCloseDate` = '5/5/2009' '?*

```
SELECT TD.TrainingID
FROM TrainingDetail TD
  JOIN Training T ON T.TrainingID = TD.TrainingID
WHERE (CompletionDate BETWEEN date1 AND date2) OR TrainingCloseDate = '5/5/2009'
```